# onload img remove class of parent div

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding an animation on div if image loading and I want to remove that class when image is loaded

```
<div class="card-image placeholder">
    <a [routerLink]="somelink">
    <img src="{{url}}/someimage"
         onError="this.src='image';"
         onload="this.removeClass='placeholder';">
     </a>
</div>
```

Can you please give solution to remove class placeholder when image is loaded successfully

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode

Comment: Can you please post your code on Fiddle or Codepen or even snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to remove class placeholder

```
<div class="card-image placeholder">
    <a [routerLink]="somelink">
    <img src="{{url}}/someimage"
         onError="this.src='image';"
         onload="this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('placeholder');">
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can introduce boolean property isPlaceholder with default value 'true' in component class

and modify template like this:

```
<div class="card-image" [ngClass]="{'placeholder': isPlaceholder}">
    <a [routerLink]="somelink">
    <img src="{{url}}/someimage"
         onError="this.src='image';"
         (load)="isPlaceholder = false">
     </a>
</div>
```

for adding animations, please refer to https://angular.io/guide/animations

**update**
here is the example on codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeJxaX

Comment: i found error in my code

the event must be (load) instead of (onLoad)